# jquery prevent the onclick event of a tags with specified class name

Tags: jquery

this is the code I have:

```
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

but this stops every link from working, I need it to be specific to the link that have a class of the name : "prevent"

for example : `<a class="prevent" href="#link"> </a><a href="#link1"> </a>`
in this case I want #link1 to work normally and #link will trigger `e.preventDefault();`

any ideas please? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('a.prevent').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

You should read: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I used this : 'a > .prevent' . totally mistaken. thank you Jory

Answer (score 3):

You can select the anchors based on their class names:

```
$('a.prevent').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```